# Python FastAPI base path control

Tags: python, fastapi

When I use FastAPI , how can I sepcify a base path for the web-service?

To put it another way - are there arguments to the FastAPI object that can set the end-point and any others I define, to a different root path?

For example , if I had the code with the spurious argument `root` below, it would attach my `/my_path` end-point to `/my_server_path/my_path` ?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI(debug = True, root = 'my_server_path') 

@app.get("/my_path")
def service( request : Request ):
    return { "message" : "my_path" }
```

Comment: I can get something similar to work by wrapping the path argument in a function which prepends the base URI e.g. `@app.get( make_path("/my_path") ` where `make_path` just prepends a string like `def make_path( x : str ) -> str: return "/my_server_path" + x`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use an `APIRouter` and add it to the app after adding the paths:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

prefix_router = APIRouter(prefix="/my_server_path")

# Add the paths to the router instead
@prefix_router.get("/my_path")
def service( request : Request ):
    return { "message" : "my_path" }

# Now add the router to the app
app.include_router(prefix_router)
```

When adding the router first and then adding paths it does now work. It seems that the paths are not detected dynamically.

Note: a path prefix must start with `/` (Thanks to Harshal Perkh for this)

Answer (score 2):

From documentation, if you are using a reverse proxy then you could  achieve the same with

`uvicorn main:app --root-path /api/v1`

reference https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/?h=prefix#testing-locally-with-traefik

Comment: doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the [prefix](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#another-module-with-apirouter) option.

Add this after creating `app`:

`app.include_router(prefix="/my_server_path")`

Comment: This doesn't work with my recent FastAPI version.

Comment: What version are you using?