# Including a base path in a FastApi application

Tags: json, fastapi, openapi

I am new to FastAPI and I need some help. I have created a fastapi application and I need to include a base url from which I can make requests to multiple endpoints for example

127.0.0.1:8000/api/router_1/endpoint_1

127.0.0.1:8000/api/router_1/endpoint_2

127.0.0.1:8000/api/router_2/endpoint_1

127.0.0.1:8000/api/router_2/endpoint_2

so i need to include "api" in the url as a base path. My endpoints are grouped in routers, for example i have a file router_1.py inside a folder routers where i define the following

```
router = APIRouter(
prefix="/router_1",
tags=["rooter_1"])
```

so that documentation and application are organized by this grouping.

In my main.py i have initialized the FastAPI with the following attributes:

```
app = FastAPI(
    title="Test API",
    description="Test description",
    version="1.0.0",
    root_path="/api",
    docs_url="/api/docs",
    openapi_url="/openapi.json")
```

When i load the page 127.0.0.1:8000/api/docs

I get the following error

**Fetch error Not Found /api/openapi.json**

when I change the openapi_url to the following

openapi_url="/api/openapi.json"

in order to include root_path I also get an error

**Fetch error Not Found /api/api/openapi.json**

but when I put root_path in comment everything seems to work fine either having
openapi_url="/openapi.json" or openapi_url="/api/openapi.json" enabled.
What am I doing wrong and how can i include a root_path without having the issue mentioned with openapi schema?

Comment: The `root_path` is for documentation only - i.e. it's meant to mean that the actual path differs from the base path handled by the application, for example because a reverse proxy handles a different path when accessing - see https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/#about-root_path . The easiest way is to create use a base router (`APIRouter`) with a `prefix`, then register the other routers under that instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219200/python-fastapi-base-path-control

Comment: I thought it was a parameter to be included in the endpoints url! I will test the solution and provide a feedback, thank you!

Comment: you can add something like `app.include_router(router, prefix="/api")` and remove `root_path` from `Fastapi`

[https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#import-the-apirouter](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#import-the-apirouter)