# working with fastapi root_path attribute and nginx on ec2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, fastapi

i'm trying to set up a fastapi server on aws ec2.
it's a part of a full stack web app and i want all the requests to the backend part go through [mydomian]/api (i have the domain up and running), doing so with defining the "root_path" attribute of my fastapi app to be /api. currently testing on the basic "/" GET endpoint, requesting `[mydomain]/api` i'm getting `{"detail":"Not Found"}` in the response.

this my main.py for the fastapi app-

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI(root_path="/api")



@app.get("/")
async def base(request: Request):
    return {"message": "Hello World", "root_path": request.scope.get("root_path")}
```

and this is the nginx config, also navigating requests to a react app.

```
server {
  server_name ******.*****;
  root /home/ubuntu/code/frontend/app/build;
  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/******.*****;/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/******.*****;/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = ******.****) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name ******.*****;;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

trying to avoid using a fastapi router at this point.
also tried:

- adding "/api" at the end of proxy_pass.
- running `uvicorn main:app --reload --root-path /api`

[the root_path docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/#about-root_path) says the responsibility is more on the nginx side.

also worth to mention that testing locally, i'm getting to the "/" by using localhost:8000, also without "/api"

feeling like i'm missing something pretty basic.
thanks for those who can help!

Answer (score 0):

The root_path is for documentation only - i.e. it's meant to mean that the actual path differs from the base path handled by the application, for example because a reverse proxy handles a different path when accessing - see [about root-path in the FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/behind-a-proxy/#about-root_path).

The easiest way is to get the actual URL mounted under a specific path is to [use a base router (APIRouter) with a prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219200/python-fastapi-base-path-control), then register the other routers under that instead.

If you want nginx to handle the transformation for you, you can add a trailing slash to your proxy pass - [that means that the complete path won't be appended to the path for the location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759345/nginx-trailing-slash-in-proxy-pass-url).

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! i considered using a router, but what if i want to add other routers in the future, and want to reach them with "router1_prefix/router2_prefix"?
do i just need to create router 2 with "router1_prefix/router2_prefix" instead of "router2_prefix"?

Comment: `router_1.include_router(router_2)` would register `router_2` under the prefix given for `router_1`. It's routers all the way down.